# Eliminate red polygons and join adjacent ones

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How I can eliminate the red polygons and join them; the adjacent ones biggest one.

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Eliminate tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/eliminate.htm).

I am making the assumption that your red polygons are in the same layer as the other polygons.
Follow this sequence:

1. Select all your red polygons.
2. Open the Eliminate Tool (**Data Management Tools > Generalization > Eliminate**)
3. Set the Input layer to be your polygon layer (the one that has all the red polygons already selected)
4. Set an output location & layer name
5. Un-check the box that reads *"Eliminating polygon by border"* (see image below).  This will make your selected polygons merge to their bordering polygon with the largest area.
6. Leave the '*Exclusion Expression*' and the '*Exclusion Layer*' fields blank.
7. Run the tool.

Please note that this tool is only available with an **Advanced** licence.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I use eliminate tool it only eliminates the red polygons that are adjacent like in the picture from 1 to the number 2. From 3 polygons now it has 2 polygons.
But they are not merged with the yellow ones.

EXCLUSION layer I used the expression not to eliminate the polygon with yellow one.
Do you have any expression or how to do it?

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: Did you select ALL your red polygons before you ran the tool?  Make sure all red polygons are selected and make sure your exclusion layer & exclusion expression are both blank.

Comment: If this has helped solve your problem, please mark the answer as solved so that it can help others in the future